# How can spring-cloud-stream kafka consumer automatic re consum unacknowledge message?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

When i manually acknowledge offsets in a consumer application, but i want consumer can re get unacknowledge message auto, but i cant do it success.

this is my config yml:

```
cloud:
  stream:
    kafka:
      binder:
        brokers: ****:****
        za-nodes: ****
        replication-factor: 1
      bindings:
       input:
         consumer: 
         auto-commit-offset: false
         auto-commit-on-error: false
         reset-offsets: true
```

Answer (score 0):

The property `resetOffsets` doesn't seem to be used now: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/48#issuecomment-273111200.

By default the consumer's `auto.offset.reset` will be set to `latest` (i.e. If you **don't** explicitly set a group for the consumer binding by using `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group`)

Comment: i setted group 。if restart the application, it's ok.
but I want to retrieve the unacknowledge message without restarting the application

Comment: you don't have to set the group if you want to start from the 'latest'. Also, for manual ack you can see this example: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_example_setting_literal_autocommitoffset_literal_false_and_relying_on_manual_acking

Answer (score 0):

Kafka does not have the ability to acknowledge individual messages - once the offset for a group/partition has been saved, all prior messages are considered 'acknowledged' - what manual acknowledgment allows is to defer the offset commit process in situations where for example the message is handled asynchronously (and automatic acknowledgment would save the offset before the message is actually process).

`resetOffsets` is not currently supported (it was a feature that we essentially dropped after we moved to the new consumer client - see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/67) but unfortunately the documentation does not reflect this.